# I need to create a function that sends an email, why it shows null when i call it in my main to confirm if it was sent?

Tags: java, backend

I need a hand, I'm learning about programming oriented to objects, so I'm doing a task. I created a class named Email, which contains some atributes. And i created an interface with 3 functions my email should have. He needs to: Send an email, Its called as ENVIAR in my repository(recieves as parameter a string message, and an Email), a method called RECIBIR that keeps that message as lastMessage, and another method called LEER which means read, which shows the lastMessage.

I'm having trouble trying to send the message, its like its not going to the direction of the new Email, or I'm doing it wrong, probably.

[This is my class Email. Here u can see my code where I'm trying to create the function to send an email to another new Email](https://github.com/AndreaAldana/Forge-6/blob/master/src/TallerCorreo/Email.java)

This is my main where I'm basically creating like a page where u register and create an email. In my sout I was trying to get the lastmassage that i was emailing to Email b, but it shows null, so its not sending anything :(.

```
    package TallerCorreo;


   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class MainCorreo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Bienvenido a correos Cmail, por favor, ingrese sus 
    datos para completar su registro");
    System.out.println("Ingrese un nombre");
    String nombre = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese una dirección");
    String direccion = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese una contraseña");
    String contrasenha = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("¡Registro realizado con éxito!");

    Email a = new Email("Andrea", "andrea@gmail.com", "123");


    Email b = new Email(nombre,direccion,contrasenha);

    a.enviar("Hello", b);

    System.out.println(a.getUltimoMensaje());



   }
 }
```

So if anybody can help me please :( I'm new at this I really want to learn more.

[Just in case, this is repository where I have all the exercise I'm doing, It's called TallerCorreo.](https://github.com/AndreaAldana/Forge-6)

Comment: I don't see where do you set the `ultimoMensaje` attribute in the provided code.

Comment: You might want to try [StackOverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it via calling `setUltimoMensaje` function with `Email` argument.

```
public void enviar(String mensaje, Email destino) {
    destino.setUltimoMensaje(mensaje);
    System.out.println("Su mensaje ha sido enviado con éxito");
}
```